# finding an element based on both parent and sibling

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, webdriver

```
<div id="Template_ctl16_ctl01_Location1_TreeView" style="overflow:auto;display:block;" tabindex="0">
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="cubek1z1" class="nrf03d0190-m">
<table class="nrf03d0190-n" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="nrf03d0190-5" onmouseover="if(window._f$0)_f$4(this)">
<img class="nrf03d0190-0" alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=M7gWkIUDj3IRN9CBh9GLLzF4VuNso-dKy3Rotx5PGdC0uT3ydQno5rIb-NZmtrRHU0LzVzM8VyBHLkbIFzfsDBifsXik5X8cfF8dTTpyh1L9n2Y-L0bYn1s4tciLXrau0&t=634787380317074324">
</td>
<td onmouseover="if(window._f$0)_f$5(this)">
<img class="nrf03d0190-0" alt="" src="/WebResource.axd?d=7sz-askeAWhF9r519BFO7s5XwSCLvPpgGPOJYyJ_GLevh8OESKMb_rEoVjUoei4tRoBBcLE2t0k2ici5YCEklBIiUx9pRM4ms_q18X9HGDBhaxHQlS5wQ5h-v7WaMEtq0&t=634787380317074324">
</td>
<td class="nrf03d0190-7">
<div class="nrf03d0190-l" onmouseover="if(window._f$0)_f$2(this)">All Locations</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<div style="visibility:hidden;font-size:1px;background-color:Silver;height:7px;" onmouseout="if(window._f$0)_f$50(this)" onmouseover="if(window._f$0)_f$4Z(this)"> </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Currently I know that the following works:
//div[.='All Locations']//tr/td[2]//img

That syntax will return the second image which is correct. What I want to do however is return that same image but also qualify it with the main div id (i.e Template_ctl16_ctl01_Location1_TreeView), it needs to be done this way because there will be a second table in the webpage that has the same inner text values.

Read quite a few xpath docs but have not been able to piece the parent function and this aspect together.

Here is my current selenium code:
var allLocationChkBox =
                WebBrowser.Current.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[.='All Locations']//td[2]//img"));
            allLocationChkBox.Click();

Just need to add the qualiyfing main div id onto the variable before clicking the checkbox.

Anyone able to shed light on this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This is rather contradictory: 1. There isn't any `img` element in the provided XML document. 2. There isn't any `div`, too. 3. There isn't any element whose string value is the string `'All Location'`. Please, edit and correct the question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi Dimitre, I have edited the post with the true html. Originally i didn't put it all in as i was trying to reduce noise, but i can see it all needed to be there. Could you have another look please?

Comment: Have you tried using cssSelectors?

Comment: @GavM, that's a good development. However there are still problems: this isn't a well-formed document (unclosed `img` tags and missing closing `</div>`). Also, the XPath expression you provide cannot select anything, because the closest to "All Location" is "All Locations" -- the equality test would fail.

Comment: @Tarken Hi tarken. I used ccsify to convert the initial locator (i.e the one that works but it appears that the css provided is not supported by Selenium Webdriver which is how i am using it.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi Dimitre. I have corrected the typo on the equality test. The document itself i agree is not well formed however it is not one that I can get easily changed by my developers. I posted the html into http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ to check it displayed correctly. Any thoughts on how to qualify it with the main div id (Template_ctl16_ctl01_Location1_TreeView)?

Comment: What language are you using? Java?

Comment: @GavM, It seems to me that you want to produce another XML document, with different structure (only a specific div and only a specific text node). This is impossible to do with a pure XPath expression only, because by definition XPath is a *query* language for XML documents and as such the evaluation of any XPath expression never changes the source XML document(s) and never produces a new document.

Comment: In java I would do it with somethin like this:   `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(div[id='Template_ctl16_ctl01_Location1_TreeView'] tr td[2] img))` . That should qualify it

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi Dimitre. I'm not writing another XML document. I may not have explained this well but I am using selenium to locate an object on the page. In another part of the same webpage there will be a second tree expand (+) control with checkbox also with the label 'All locations'. All I want to do is find them in a unique way using the main div id as the qualifier.

Comment: @GavM, It would be good if you provide just a small example that only illustrates the problem. Then it would be easier for us to understand what exactly is required.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hi Dimitre, I have posted a screenshot. Hope that helps. Thanks for persisting with the question.

Comment: @Tarken I will see if i can convert it. Thanks

Comment: Consider providing a complete example of what you currently have over at http://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the XPath that you provided in your post, but it isn't grabbing anything.

Based off the structure you've posted, try the following XPath:

```
"//table[contains(@id, 'Table1')]/*/*/td[2]"
```

This will give you the td that contains the image you're looking for.  All you need to do is change 'Table1' to the id of the table you want to interact with.  This should work if the structure is the same for all the tables you're working with.

If you want to be more exact, you can use the following:

```
"//table[contains(@id, 'Table1')]/*/*/td[contains(@class, 'foo2')]"
```

This will grab the same td, but it's a bit more fine-tuned.  You'll need to change the table id, and the class for the td, since it seems that they're different for each td.

Let me know if this works, or if it's not exactly you were looking for.

Comment: Hi MPBSDSU, I have revised the html. Could you have another look. I tried your syntax based on the old html but without success. Many thanks.

Comment: Hello again, GavM.  Unfortunately, like Dimitre has stated in the comments section, it will be difficult to select specific elements if the document is not well-formed.  I know it may be a bit much to ask, but is there any way to directly access the page that you're working on?  I may be able to find something if I can directly interact with the page on my side.

Comment: @MPBSDSU Hi MPBSDSU using your initial code above as a basis I was able to get what I needed. The xpath was: //div[@id='Template_ctl16_ctl01_Location1_TreeView']/div/table/tbody/tr/td//div[.='All Locations']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img. Unfortunately I cannot Vote Up as I am new on StackOverflow but thanks to you and all the other responders. I appreciate it wasn't easy assisting me as I didn't give as much info as you guys would have liked (company security reasons) but wasn't deliberately being difficult.